# Cannot break the loop cycle (while n!=4)

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am very noob at coding and I keep having the same error over and over. The loop is supposed to be run until correctGuesses reaches the value of 4, and then break the cycle and print 'terminal hacked'. I am running this in a private platform and I keep getting the same error "Your loop needs to stop when all 4 characters have been guessed". Does someone know why? Thank you so much in advance!

var correctGuesses = 0;
var randNum;

while (correctGuesses!==4) {

```
randNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

  
if(randNum===1) {
 
         correctGuesses=correctGuesses+1;
         console.log("Found "+correctGuesses+ " characters");

} else if (randNum===2) {
            
         correctGuesses=0;
         console.log('Starting over');
    
} else if (randNum===3) {
    
correctGuesses=0;   
 }
```

}  console.log('terminal hacked');

So I finally found the error. I had to put a if (correctGuesses===4){break;} right after the correctGuesses++ reached 4, because the goal was the cycle to be broken when correctGuesses===4. It was a school exercise and it clearly said that the cycle should end afater 4 correct guesses but I did not fully understand that before writing the code. Thank you all.

Comment: Is it possible you get `randNum == 2` BEFORE you get four correct guesses? Because when that happens, you restart from zero, and the chance of getting four `1`s without getting a `2` in between is quite low.

Comment: Where are the four characters?

Comment: _"The loop is supposed to be run until `correctGuesses` reaches the value of 4,"_ - that is what your current code is doing. You only increment the `correctGuesses` variable if generated random number is 1 and you reset `correctGuesses` when generated random number is 2 or 3. BTW, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` will only give you three random numbers --> 0, 1, 2. so last if condition is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Given how the assignment is worded and the fact that random numbers are, well, *random*, my guess is that the platform you're writing this code for has overridden `Math.random` to supply a specific sequence of numbers and then they check the output you produce matches.

This means means that you simply need to follow the specifications and the outcome is not based on luck. There are two problems here

## Generating an number between 1 and 3

You currently only generate a number between `0` and `2`, since you're rounding *down*.

```js
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

console.log(randNum);
```

To get output between `1` and `3`, the traditional way is to just add `1` to the output. Or more generally, you add the *minimum* to the output and generate between `0` and `max - min`:

```js
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

console.log("random between 2-5:", randomBetween(0, 2));
console.log("random between 1-3:", randomBetween(1, 3));
```

## Keep `correctGuesses` the same value when `randNum` is `3`

Cight now you're resetting `correctGuesses` to `0` when `randNum === 3`. So, if you fix the problem with being able to generate a `3`, then this will be incorrect as per the requirement. The assignment doesn't have any other requirement for what happens when that number is generated, so since you have to keep the number unchanged, it's very simple - you don't do anything. Simply remove the entire `if` and your code would work as the requirement asks.

## Conclusion

You code should look like this after you've made the changes:

```js
var correctGuesses = 0;
var randNum;

while (correctGuesses !== 4) {
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; //add 1 to generate numbers 1-3

  if (randNum === 1) {
    correctGuesses = correctGuesses + 1;
    console.log("Found " + correctGuesses + " characters");
  } else if (randNum === 2) {
    correctGuesses = 0;
    console.log('Starting over');
  }
  //don't do anything for randNum === 3

}
console.log('terminal hacked');
```